# errors when using fpca package in R

Tags: r, functional-programming

I am using the fpca package to apply the reduced rank model in James et al. (2000), but every time I try to use the fpca.score function, it returns me this error:

```
Error in eigenfuncs.u[gridtime, 1:K] : subscript out of bounds
```

So I pulled out the source code:

```
function (data.m, grids.u, muhat, eigenvals, eigenfuncs, sig2hat, K) 
{
    temp <- table(data.m[, 1])
    n <- length(temp)
    m.l <- as.vector(temp)
    result <- matrix(0, n, K)
    N <- length(grids.u)
    evalmat <- diag(eigenvals[1:K])
    current <- 0
    eigenfuncs.u <- t(eigenfuncs)
    data.u <- matrix(as.numeric(as.vector(data.m[, -1])),nrow=nrow(data.m[,-1]), ncol = ncol(data.m[, -1]))
    for (i in 1:n) {
        Y <- as.vector(data.u[(current + 1):(current + m.l[i]), 1])
        meastime <- data.u[(current + 1):(current + m.l[i]), 2]
        gridtime <- ceiling(N * meastime)
        muy <- muhat[gridtime]
        Phiy <- matrix(eigenfuncs.u[gridtime, 1:K], ncol = K)
        Sigy <- Phiy %*% evalmat %*% t(Phiy) + sig2hat * diag(m.l[i])
        temp.y <- matrix(Y - muy)
        result[i, ] <- evalmat %*% t(Phiy) %*% solve(Sigy, temp.y)
        current <- current + m.l[i]
    }
    return(result)
}
```

data.m is a three-column data matrix whose first column is id, second column is measurement, third column is time. It is also the input of fpca.mle function whose outputs include the other inputs of the above fpca.score function: grids, muhat, eigenvals, eigenfuncs, sig2hat, K.

Apparently the error occurs here

```
eigenfuncs.u[gridtime, 1:K]
```

which comes from

```
N <- length(grids.u)
meastime <- data.u[(current + 1):(current + m.l[i]), 2]
gridtime <- ceiling(N * meastime)
```

Is there any fda guru who knows how to fix this? Deeply appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue might come from mismatch between grids value and the values of time in your data. Using Newton algorithm, default value for grids is seq(0,1,0.002), so the time data needs to be re-scaled to fall between (0,1).

Comment: boundaries not included? could you suggest ways to exclude 0 and 1 plz? I normalized time stamps but always included the boundaries... Thanks so much!